# Possible to write this query without aggregate function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT l.LocID, COUNT(ulr.UserID)
FROM Locations l
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserLocationRights ulr ON l.LocID = ulr.LocID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Devices d ON l.LocID = d.LocID
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserModelRights umr ON d.ModelName = umr.ModelName
    AND ulr.UserID = umr.UserID
GROUP BY l.LocID, ulr.UserID, d.ModelName
ORDER BY l.LocID, ulr.UserID
```

I want the results to be the `LocID` of *all* of the entries in `Locations` and the second column to be the number of Users who have rights to this location that also have the rights to *at least* one of the `Devices` in the `Location` which is determined by the entries in `UserModelRights`.

I can only figure out how to get what I want like this:

```
SELECT l.LocID, IsNull(UserHasModelRightInLoc.UserCount, 0) UserCount
FROM Locations l
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ulr.LocID, COUNT(UserModelRightsPerLocation.UserID) UserCount
    FROM UserLocRights ulr
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT l.LocID, umr.UserID
        FROM UserModelRights umr
        INNER JOIN Devices d ON umr.ModelName = d.ModelName
        INNER JOIN Locations l ON d.LocID = l.LocID
        GROUP BY umr.ModelName, umr.UserID, l.LocID
        ) UserModelRightsPerLocation ON ulr.LocID = UserModelRightsPerLocation.LocID
        AND ulr.UserID = UserModelRightsPerLocation.UserID
    GROUP BY ulr.LocID
    ) UserHasModelRightInLoc ON l.LocID = UserHasModelRightInLoc.LocID
ORDER BY l.LocID
```

I don't know if this is possible, but I *assume* that there could be a way to use `GROUP BY` to get what I want using my first, much smaller query. The issue is that I think I need to do multiple `GROUP BY` in a specific order and I don't know if that's possible or makes sense in SQL.

Is there a way to get the result I want without using an aggregate function? If not, maybe narrow it down to a single one?

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired results? Just reverse engineering your query to write a different version, throwing it over the wall, and guessing if it still gets the right results is going to be tedious.

Comment: No there's no way to COUNT without using an aggregate function, and why would you want to?

Comment: How do expect to aggregate without aggregate functioin?

Comment: `"there's no way to COUNT without using an aggregate function"` : This is not correct @TabAlleman. Maybe aggregate is best solution but you can COUNT using a lot of other options. For example using ROW_NUMBER() or RANK functions with TOP 1. Again, I am not saying that this is the right solution but only that COUNT can be done without aggregate.

Comment: @RonenAriely technically neither of those alternatives are counting. They would produce the same value but not because they were counting.

Comment: @RonenAriely Really?  How do you `COUNT` using `TOP 1`?

Comment: @Eric if you use for example ROW_NUMBER without partitioning and you select the last number then you get the number of rows

Comment: @RonenAriely The OP obviously has partitioning from all those `GROUP BYs`.

Comment: @Eric, I did not comment to the question but to the wrong assumption that you must use aggregate function to COUNT. Once the OP will provide DDL+DML I will, address the question...COUNT without aggregate:  `DECLARE @T TABLE (x int); INSERT @T(x) VALUES (2),(5),(7),(6); WITH MyCTE as (SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x DESC) FROM @T) SELECT TOP 1 RN FROM MyCTE ORDER BY RN DESC`

Comment: And again! I am not saying that someone should use it but simply that it was a wrong statement ;-)

Comment: @SeanLange , As I said there are multiple options. If you really want to get into philosophical discussion about the definition of counting, then you can also use a cursor in order to count row by row (without any aggregate function), which is the definition of counting! Simply use a loop and COUNT the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this a bit hard to follow without sample data.  But based on your description, this might do what you want:

```
SELECT l.LocID, COUNT(DISTINCT ulr.UserID)
FROM Locations l LEFT JOIN
     UserLocationRights ulr
     ON l.LocID = ulr.LocID LEFT JOIN
     Devices d
     ON l.LocID = d.LocID LEFT JOIN
     UserModelRights umr
     ON d.ModelName = umr.ModelName AND
        ulr.UserID = umr.UserID
GROUP BY l.LocID
ORDER BY l.LocID;
```

Comment: This sounds very close to what I was trying to do, if not exactly. The only problem is I am getting different counts than my query in my OP with the aggregate functions is returning and I'm not sure why yet...

Comment: I got the results to match up by changing it to this: `SELECT l.LocID, COUNT(DISTINCT ulr.UserID)
FROM LocStruct l
LEFT JOIN Devices d ON l.LocID = d.LocID
LEFT JOIN UserModelRights umr ON d.ModelName = umr.ModelName
LEFT JOIN UserLocRights ulr ON l.LocID = ulr.LocID
 AND ulr.UserID = umr.UserID
GROUP BY l.LocID
ORDER BY l.LocID;`